# One loop or two? (how to read the IL)

Tags: c#, linq, loops, foreach, il

The C# below is a very simple loop but I think it is two loops. A coworker of mine says that he thinks it is a single loop. Can you tell me if it is one loop or two loops? Can you also tell me how to read the IL and prove to my coworker that it is two loops?

```
var ints = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4};

foreach (var i in ints.Where(x => x != 2))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

If it turns out that this is actually one loop that is cool to. I would still like to know how I can read the IL and see that it is only one loop.

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       137 (0x89)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init ([0] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32> ints,
           [1] int32 i,
           [2] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32> '<>g__initLocal0',
           [3] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<int32> CS$5$0000,
           [4] bool CS$4$0001)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  newobj     instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  stloc.2
  IL_0007:  ldloc.2
  IL_0008:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0009:  callvirt   instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>::Add(!0)
  IL_000e:  nop
  IL_000f:  ldloc.2
  IL_0010:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_0011:  callvirt   instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>::Add(!0)
  IL_0016:  nop
  IL_0017:  ldloc.2
  IL_0018:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_0019:  callvirt   instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>::Add(!0)
  IL_001e:  nop
  IL_001f:  ldloc.2
  IL_0020:  ldc.i4.4
  IL_0021:  callvirt   instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>::Add(!0)
  IL_0026:  nop
  IL_0027:  ldloc.2
  IL_0028:  stloc.0
  IL_0029:  nop
  IL_002a:  ldloc.0
  IL_002b:  ldsfld     class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32,bool> ConsoleApplication1.Program::'CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate2'
  IL_0030:  brtrue.s   IL_0045
  IL_0032:  ldnull
  IL_0033:  ldftn      bool ConsoleApplication1.Program::'<Main>b__1'(int32)
  IL_0039:  newobj     instance void class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32,bool>::.ctor(object,
                                                                                      native int)
  IL_003e:  stsfld     class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32,bool> ConsoleApplication1.Program::'CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate2'
  IL_0043:  br.s       IL_0045
  IL_0045:  ldsfld     class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32,bool> ConsoleApplication1.Program::'CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate2'
  IL_004a:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::Where<int32>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>,
                                                                                                                                       class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<!!0,bool>)
  IL_004f:  callvirt   instance class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<!0> class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<int32>::GetEnumerator()
  IL_0054:  stloc.3
  .try
  {
    IL_0055:  br.s       IL_0067
    IL_0057:  ldloc.3
    IL_0058:  callvirt   instance !0 class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<int32>::get_Current()
    IL_005d:  stloc.1
    IL_005e:  nop
    IL_005f:  ldloc.1
    IL_0060:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
    IL_0065:  nop
    IL_0066:  nop
    IL_0067:  ldloc.3
    IL_0068:  callvirt   instance bool [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerator::MoveNext()
    IL_006d:  stloc.s    CS$4$0001
    IL_006f:  ldloc.s    CS$4$0001
    IL_0071:  brtrue.s   IL_0057
    IL_0073:  leave.s    IL_0087
  }  // end .try
  finally
  {
    IL_0075:  ldloc.3
    IL_0076:  ldnull
    IL_0077:  ceq
    IL_0079:  stloc.s    CS$4$0001
    IL_007b:  ldloc.s    CS$4$0001
    IL_007d:  brtrue.s   IL_0086
    IL_007f:  ldloc.3
    IL_0080:  callvirt   instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
    IL_0085:  nop
    IL_0086:  endfinally
  }  // end handler
  IL_0087:  nop
  IL_0088:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Comment: What makes you think it's two loops? What has looking at IL got to do with it?

Comment: I'd guess two loops, the full LINQ will execute first on all elements, then pass the result to the foreach? Would be cool if someone knew, I'm not that asked to look it up :P

Comment: @starlight54 not exactly. `Where` returns an iterator, which is an object with `Current` property and `MoveNext` method. It processes its input lazily. On each execution of the `foreach` body, `Where`'s `MoveNext` is called, and it will internally loop through `ints` a bit further till it finds one that matches the condition, then return it. However, the `ints` list is still only iterated once. It's really all part of the same loop.

Comment: Just measure it, the difference between O(n) and O(n^2) is easy to see back.

Comment: LINQ is lazy. It is one loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiler translates your code into try-finally block, first it calls `GetEnumerator` method on the source, (which is the iterator returned from `Where)` then enters the try block.

The first insruction:

```
IL_0055:  br.s       IL_0067
```

Jumps to the `IL_0067` to call `MoveNext` on the iterator and then loads the result of `MoveNext` into the local variable (as the weird name suggests (CS$4$0001) this is a compiler generated variable):

```
IL_006d:  stloc.s    CS$4$0001
IL_006f:  ldloc.s    CS$4$0001
```

This instruction checks if the result return from `MoveNext` is `true` and if it is jumps back to the `IL_0057`

```
IL_0071:  brtrue.s   IL_0057
```

Then the execution continues, the same operation is keep running until `MoveNext` returns `false`.So yes, there is one loop in the code.

You can find more information about the `IL` instructions in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes_fields(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

In addition to this the code before `try` block might seem confusing but it basically creates a `Func<int, bool>` delegate which is your lambda expression (`x => x != 2`) then passes it to `Where` method.And loads the result of it into the 3. (actually it's fourth, `3` is the index) local variable in this line:

```
IL_0054:  stloc.3
```

Which is an `IEnumerator<int>` as you can see in the parameter list.Then your loop uses that iterator.

Comment: "there is another loop executed in Where method behind the scenes" this is not true in the sense apparently intended by the question. I.e. while it's true that LINQ is implemented with iterator methods, which have loops in them, there is not any _nested_ loop here. At run-time, it all winds up being effectively one big loop, with each iterator method (here, just the one) being a state machine called by the next-outer level of loop.

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes you are correct though I didn't mean it's a nested loop. I meant there is another loop executed behind the scenes.So this loop runs based on the result of that hidden loop.

Comment: anyway I removed that part because it seems it is not true for this particular case. because this overload of Where just returns an iterator instance so there is no another loop going on...

Comment: "So this loop runs based on the result of that hidden loop." -- well, that's my point. This loop doesn't run on the _result_ of the hidden loop. The two loops run concurrently, as a single larger loop. That's why an iterator instance is returned; that's how iterator methods all work. The loop in the iterator method isn't executed all at once...each iteration occurs only as needed as other code enumerates the iteration (i.e. in another loop).

Answer (score 1):

It's a single loop. The `Where` method won't execute first on all item, it will filter the items as you enumerate them.

The `Where` method doesn't produce a collection that you enumerate, it creates an enumerator that will test the condition on the items as you enumerate them. The items will be processed in the same was as:

```
foreach (var i in ints) {
  if (i != 2) {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
  }
}
```

The code contains shorthand code for creating a list, looping using an enumerator, and a bunch of other stuff, so it can be hard to see how it relates to the IL code. This is approximately what the code would look like when the shorthand code is expanded:

```
Func<int, bool> cachedDelegate;

void Main(string[] args) {
  List<int> temp;
  int i;
  List<int> ints;
  IEnumerator<int> enumerator;

  temp = new List<int>();
  temp.Add(1);
  temp.Add(2);
  temp.Add(3);
  temp.Add(4);
  ints = temp;

  if (cachedDelegate == null) {
    cachedDelegate = new Func<int, bool>(Check);
  }
  enumerator = ints.Where(cachedDelegate).GetEnumerator();
  try {
    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
      i = enumerator.Current;
      Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
  } finally {
    if (enumerator != null) {
      enumerator.Dispose();
    }
  }
}

bool Check(int x) {
  return x != 2;
}
```